# Is bookdown's math render down?

Tags: latex, bookdown

I have working `.Rmd` files that contain latex syntax (rendering correctly). However, when I render using the `bookdown` package, I have experienced that the latex output is incorrect.
I went to check in the source (aka https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-syntax.html#math-expressions) and I see that the render is not correct there either!

[image]

I see similar behavior for bookdown's `preview_chapter()` rendering but not for Rmarkdown knit of a toy example. I see similar behavior changing web browser.

**Is this something on my end? Are there updates I need to do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an issue on your end, but a server problem (the default MathJax CDN server in **bookdown** was down). I just changed the server, and the problem should be gone if you

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that Yihui Xie's answer is helpful. I didn't have `devtools` installed in **RStudio**, so I used:

> install.packages('devtools')

After this, I duly followed Yihui's recommendation and ran:

> devtools::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')

After this, the problem was solved and maths were rendered correctly in the `gitbook` format.